# Get the current group section displayed on Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Hello I want to know if there is a way to know which section a list view is currently displayed. I have a grouped `ListView` which contains headers and I need to know which section is been displayed.

For instance on iOS I can use `NSIndexPath` which has to members.  `section` and `row` the section object tells me **Inside the scroll event** which group is currently displayed on the screen. Is there something similar on Android?

Here is an image to understand this a little bit more:

[image]

I want to know this because I want to mimic a sticky header that will change based on the scroll event. **I cannot use 3rd party libraries for sticky headers because it will break my Xamarin shared code.** If this is possible then I think I can achieve this.

Comment: Any comments on the down vote will be appreciate it.

Comment: You must handle the selections through the `ItemTapped` event instead of` ItemSelected`. Then you can get it in the `(ItemTappedEventArgs) e.Group`. (Sorry for the poor english) - Not the 'downvoter'

Comment: Hello @DiegoRafaelSouza I appreciate the comment but the header will change based on the scroll event of the ListView not until the user taps or Selects the List item.

Comment: So you may do it in the `ItemAppearing`or  `ItemDisappearing` events of your listview, changing some internal information at your code behind

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza unfortunately `ItemAppearing` and `ItemDisappearing` do not work as expected specially ItemDisappearing besides I still need to know when the header is going to be fully visible so I can still show the previous header until the new one is fully visible.

Comment: I got it. Then I think the best way to do that is through in a custom renderer, but unfortunately I can't help with this. Good Luck